# Is it possible to export a WF diagram to visio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, workflow-foundation, diagram, visio

I would like to be able to export my WF diagram from visual studio 2008 into Visio so I can better show it to non-programmers. Dose anyone know if its possible? I haven't come across any mention of it before, and I don't see anything that jumps out at me from VS.

[EDIT: WF = Windows Workflow Foundation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the designer, click on the Workflow menu item and select "Save as Image" or "Copy to Clipboard"

Answer (score 1):

I will say up front that I don't know how exactly what a WWF diagram is but wouldn't it be possible to just export the diagram to a JPEG file. If all you need to do is show it to people an image would probably work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda, sorta.  I don't know if you/your company has the budget for it, but I've worked with K2 Workflow works natively within Visio.  You can build the workflow in Visio, and bind it to elements in K2 workflow/Windows workflow foundation.  Give it a shot at http://www.k2.com.  It's cheap for developers to start with, but gets real expensive at the high end.

(no this is not a shameless plug, just a product I happen to like :-) )

Answer (score 0):

In VS2015, the Workflow menu doesn't exist but you can right-click in the Designer to reach the 'Copy as Image' and 'Save as Image' options.

I had the most success with the XPS format which rendered well even when zoomed-in, and can be viewed with the built-in XPS viewer in Windows.